# Нажатие кнопки каждые 24 часа PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как можно сделать так, чтобы на кнопку можно было нажимать **`раз в 24 часа`**?

Если же я нажму на кнопку когда 24 часа не прошло, приложение должно мне под кнопкой высветить эту картинку, поверх которой будет `label`, который будет показывать сколько времени осталось до нажатия:

[image: Картинка]

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1229, 582)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(430, 120))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(4)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(501, 164))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 50px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(133, 34, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLICK ME EVERY 24 HOURS"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(430, 120))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(4)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
#        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(501, 164))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 50px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(133, 34, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 3)      # +
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLICK ME EVERY 24 HOURS"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)
        self.testTimeDisplay = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setFixedSize(150, 70)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.testTimeDisplay, 0, 2, 1, 1, 
                                  alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(1) 
        self.fl = True
        self.sec = ...
        self.updtTime()
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onClicked(self):
        if self.fl:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Title', 'Кнопка нажата, делайте что-нибудь!')
            self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60)         # 1 мин = 60 сек
            # self.dt = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().addSecs(1*60*60*24) # раз в 24 часа
            self.fl = False
            self.sec = 0
        else:
            self.flashSplash()

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        # QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
        # Возвращает количество секунд от этой даты до другой даты. 
        # Если другой datetime раньше, чем this date, возвращаемое значение будет отрицательным.

        self.sec = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().secsTo(self.dt)
        if self.sec <= 0:
            self.fl = True


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap('img11.png').scaled(500, 200, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.splash.move(self.pos() + QtCore.QPoint(70, self.size().height()))  # width()
        self.splash.show()
        self.splash.showMessage(
            '<h2 style="color:white;">Кнопка будет доступна через {} секунд</h2>'.format(self.sec), 
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)# | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.white)    

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.splash.close)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а потом это получиться оформить покрасивее, примерно так как я писал в вопросе?

Comment: еще я заметил одну вещь, после закрытия и повторного открытия приложения можно нажать еще раз, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: @imapw_ я добавил ваше покрасивее. По второму вашему вопросу: при выходе сохраняйте в файл время выхода из приложения и количество секунд до разблокировки кнопки, а при входе в приложение сравнивайте эту беду в текущим временем и корректируйте количество секунд до разблокировки кнопки.

Comment: Вы мне какой раз уже помогаете, спасибо!